# Android Camera: set Image Size and Preview Size

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

In My camera app i am trying to set the preview `surfaceView`, `imagePreview` and `Image` Sizes however no matter what i change the live preview always occupies the entire activity. there doesn't appear to be any distortion but the problem is i need to attach an overlay image that is present in the preview and must be saved in the same position in the end image.

Shouldn't the Preview size be taken in relation the the end image size as i am passing `params.getPictureSize().` `width` and `height` into the `getOptimalPreviewSize()` method?

**surfaceView Layout**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**set Image size**

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List <Camera.Size>sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
if(sizes.size() > 1){
    params.setPictureSize(sizes.get(2).width,sizes.get(2).height);// get can be value 0 - 5
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
```

**note** i am manually setting different sizes here for testing purposes

**Set Preview Size**

```
List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Camera.Size camPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes, params.getPictureSize().width , params.getPictureSize().height);
params.setPreviewSize(camPreviewSize.width, camPreviewSize.height);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
camera.setParameters(params);
camera.startPreview();
```

**getOptimalPreviewSize()**

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```